# decimal representation of an integer in R

Tags: r, integer, decimal

I am struggling with the decimal expression of an integer in R. For example, how can convert the integer, for example, x = 1, to the decimal expression in R, like x = 2.00 with the three digits requirement.

Best,
Qiong

Comment: I don't know if you can force more trailing zeros to show in the console, but you can format output with as many decimal places as you want. For example, `format(x, digits=2, nsmall=2)` or `sprintf("%1.2f", x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you display the value of an object in the console, it is implicitly calling the `print` method for the object (i.e., typing `x` in the console is the same as typing `print(x)`. I don't know of a way to force display of trailing zeros in the console through the standard `print` (short of writing your own print method to override the internal one). However, whether in the console or for any other kind of output, you can use `format` or `sprintf` to gain greater control over how results are displayed. For example:

```
x = 2

format(x, digits=2, nsmall=2)
```

> ```
> [1] "2.00"
> ```

```
sprintf("%1.2f", x)
```

> ```
> [1] "2.00"
> ```

You can even get rid of the quotation marks if you wish, using the `noquote` function:

```
noquote(format(x, digits=2, nsmall=2))
```

> ```
> [1] 2.00
> ```

```
noquote(sprintf("%1.2f", x))
```

> ```
> [1] 2.00
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice idea to use the noquote function. I like to take it. Thanks again.